# ¿Existen los sub-subdominios?

Tags: url, dominio, uri

Recientemente estoy en contacto con varios subdominios que tienen este formato: https://blog.rrhh.empresa.com/

¿Cómo leo esto?

Si **empresa.com** es el dominio y **rrhh** es el subdominio, ¿qué es **blog**?

Si **blog** es a su vez un subdominio del subdominio **rrhh**, ¿existen limitaciones de anidación, es decir, hay algo que impida que pueda crear 15 subdominios detrás de un dominio?

¡Saludos y gracias!

Comment: En realidad no hay un límite, pero se recomienda no crear más subdominios sobre otros por la legibilidad de la URL